# Sorting 2D Lists in Python 3

Tags: python, sorting

I'm having difficulty sorting multidimensional lists in python 3. I want to sort the list below **alphabetically based on the name** and then in another way based on the age in **decesending**. I have tried using the sorted function and the lambda key but I get I keep getting the same index error indicating that the list is out of range. How would I sort the entire list?

```
    mylist = []
    mylist.append([])
    mylist.append([])
    mylist.append([])
    mylist[0].append("Anna")
    mylist[0].append("Maria")
    mylist[1].append("Doctor")
    mylist[1].append("Teacher")
    mylist[2].append(36) 
    mylist[2].append(28)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as follows:

```
import operator

mylist = []
mylist.append([])
mylist.append([])
mylist.append([])
mylist[0].append("Anna")
mylist[1].append("Maria")
mylist[2].append("Aaron")
mylist[0].append("Doctor")
mylist[1].append("Teacher")
mylist[2].append("Student")
mylist[0].append(36)
mylist[1].append(28)
mylist[2].append(13)


name_sort = sorted(mylist, key = operator.itemgetter(0))
age_sort = sorted(mylist, key = operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)

print(name_sort)
print(age_sort)
```

Which prints out first a list that's sorted ascending by name and second a list that sorted descending by age:

```
>>> 
[['Aaron', 'Student', 13], ['Anna', 'Doctor', 36], ['Maria', 'Teacher', 28]]
[['Anna', 'Doctor', 36], ['Maria', 'Teacher', 28], ['Aaron', 'Student', 13]]
```

Also notice that I have changed the way your lists are created: each sublist contains all information about an "entity/person" instead of all the attributes (e.g. age, name etc.)

Comment: Is there any way I could do it without having to change the way the lists were created?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mylist = []
mylist.append([])
mylist.append([])
mylist.append([])
mylist[0].append("Anna")
mylist[1].append("Maria")
mylist[2].append("Aaron")
mylist[0].append("Doctor")
mylist[1].append("Teacher")
mylist[2].append("Student")
mylist[0].append(36)
mylist[1].append(28)
mylist[2].append(13)

mylist.sort(key=lambda x : x[2] , reverse = True)
```

*If you want sort by age in descending order...*

If you want to sort based on the age then you need to use the lambda function. **This works by  setting the key by which you want to sort the list based on an elements index position(i.e in this case the second element in the list->age).** 
Lastly `reverse = True` statement is used. This basically explains itself. It simply reverses the list thereby making it in descending order. That's it!

*If you want to sort in alphabetical order...*

The `.sort()`function works by initially using the first element in the list. So if you want to sort it in alphabetical order based on the persons name then you can simply use this line of code `mylist.sort()`.

If you still find it difficult  to understand click [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).