# Sort with custom function

Tags: python, sorting

I can sort a 2D-array in Javascript like the following:

```
const a = [[-1, 5], [3, 2], [-25, 1], [12, 3], [12, 1]]

a.sort((a,b) => {
    if (a[0] != b[0]) {
        return a[0] - b[0]
    }
    else {
        return b[1] - a[1] * 2 + 3
    }
})
```

How to perform the same task in Python?

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in `sorted` function or the similar list `sort` method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/29201774/2308683

Comment: @OneCricketeer (and @mkrieger1 ): there is something more than meets the eye in the question: the OP doesn't just want to compare using e.g. `sorted(..., key=...)`. They want to implement a specific ordering that considers any pair of values in a custom way (and, in the js example, an inconsistent one, as per [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74591284/758174)). The only thing i could think of is a class that implements the custom comparison ordering methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
x = [[-1, 5], [3, 2], [-25, 1], [12, 3], [12, 1]]
>>> sorted(x)
[[-25, 1], [-1, 5], [3, 2], [12, 1], [12, 3]]
```

If you wanted to customize the order, e.g. order by `b, a` (for each `[a, b]` sublist):

```py
>>> sorted(x, key=lambda ab: ab[::-1])
[[-25, 1], [12, 1], [3, 2], [12, 3], [-1, 5]]
```

However, in your JavaScript you define a specific comparison (not a key that is in turn used for comparison). This is a little different in Python. You would define a class that has a custom ordering. For example, here, using [`total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering):

```py
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class weird(list):
    def __lt__(a, b):
        if a[0] != b[0]:
            return a[0] < b[0]
        return b[1] < a[1] * 2 + 3
```

And now:

```py
>>> sorted([weird(xi) for xi in x])
[[-25, 1], [-1, 5], [3, 2], [12, 1], [12, 3]]
```

In JavaScript, the result is slightly different: `[[-25,1],[-1,5],[3,2],[12,3],[12,1]]` (the last two elements are swapped), why is that?

The reason is that the order you specified is not consistent:

```py
>>> weird([12,1]) < weird([12,3])
True

>>> weird([12,3]) < weird([12,1])
True
```

Thus, the order of the result is dependent on the sort implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `sorted` built-iin function with `key` parameter and define a lambda function that will sort the list according to the condition defined

```
list_ = [[-1, 5], [3, 2], [-25, 1], [12, 3], [12, 1]]
sorted_list=sorted(list_, key=lambda arr: arr[0]-arr[1])
```